# Thrift service for PHP based Thrift Client

Tags: php, service, client, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have downloaded thrift .tar file and took lib/php/src folder and I renamed it as thrift . Then in my PHP file to write PHP Thrift Client , I have following code:

```
<?php
 $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = 'thrift';

   require_once 'thrift/Thrift.php';
   require_once 'thrift/transport/TTransport.php';
   require_once 'thrift/transport/TSocket.php';
   require_once 'thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php';
   require_once 'thrift/transport/TFramedTransport.php';
   require_once 'thrift/transport/TBufferedTransport.php';

   require_once 'thrift/packages/MyService/MyService.php';
   require_once 'thrift/packages/MyService/MyService_types.php';

   $transport = new TSocket('localhost',1100);
   $transport->open();

   $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);

   $client= new MyServiceClient($protocol, $protocol);

   $result = $client->operation('param1', 'param2');

   Print 'result = ' . $result;

   $transport->close();
```

When I tried to execute it , it give error that I don't have `MyService` files. And it is correct I don't have that. I want to know that from where I can get that file or from where I can know how to write such service. I am asking that because I am not well versed with Apache Thrift. Please tell if I am doing some thing wrong or if any one knows how I can write service file and what will be in it? Will there be some sort of compiler required for just writing PHP Thrift client?

Please tell whatever you know , thanks for giving some time to my question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to compile MyService.thrift IDL file with thrift compiler to get MyService.php something like this:

`thrift --gen php MyService.thrift`

please also take a look at [this tutorial](http://chanian.com/2010/05/13/thrift-tutorial-a-php-client/)